# PyMongo: regex match document field against python variable

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I have a db with documents with this format:

```
document1:
    "source_dir": 
    [
        "D:\dir1", 
        "D:\dir2"
    ]

document2:
    "source_dir": 
    [
        "D:\dir3", 
        "D:\dir4"
    ]
```

And in Python I have this path variable:

```
path = "D:\dir1\testFile.txt"
```

How can I query the db using the "path" variable so the return value is the document which "source_dir" array field contains an item that matches the start of path variable content?

In this case, the return value would be document1, since its source_dir field contains D:\dir1 and path starts with D:\dir1.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you use Python's `pathlib` to split `path` into the parts you need, and then `db.collection.find({"source_dir": drive_and_directory})`?

Comment: Can't do that as I don't know how more info the path variable might have, so I don't know where to split it.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilise aggregation operator [$indexCP](https://docs.mongodb.com/rapid/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/) to search a string for an occurrence of a substring. The trick here is to reverse the search, using the `source_dir` value to search in the variable.

For example:

```
fullpath = "D:\\dir1\\testFile.txt"

pipeline = [
        {"$unwind": "$source_dir"},
        {"$match":{
            "$expr":{
                "$ne":[{"$indexOfCP":[fullpath, "$source_dir"]}, -1]
        }}}]
result = client.dbname.collname.aggregate(pipeline)
for doc in result:
    print(doc)
```

See also [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to find more operators

Comment: Nice!  Here's a [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d7lylnycg7c "Click me!") adaptation.